# Passing array to a function in postgresql

Tags: arrays, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a table where I want to search all records at once using a function.but my function doesn't display anything when I give inputs to it. Please if you have any idea how to write a function for it to take all values at once and print its result. I am sharing my table and function with you as under.

```
select * from v_payments ;
 entity_name | patient_name | business_entity_id | payment_type_id | entered_date 
-------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------
 patient     | ali          |                  1 |               5 | 2020-01-01
 male        | baba         |                  2 |               4 | 2020-02-01
 female      | reshma       |                  7 |               8 | 2020-03-01
```

function for it as under

```sql
create or replace function get_patient_data (b_entity_id[],p_type_id[],e_date date[]) returns table (
entity_first_name  TEXT,
  patient_first_name TEXT,
  business_entity_id INTEGER,
  payments_type_id  INTEGER,
  entry_date     DATE) as $$
begin
SELECT
  entity_name,
  patient_name,
  business_entity_id,
  payment_type_id,
  entered_date
FROM v_payments
WHERE business_entity_id = ANY($1) and payment_type_id = ANY($2) and entered_date = ($3); end; $$ language plpgsql ;
```

Comment: How you are calling above method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few problems are there in the function. i.e. `return query` was not there in the function and you are comparing `date` with `date[]` which will throw error. So the function query after fixing the error with same logic looks like below:

```sql
create or replace function get_patient_data (b_entity_id int[],p_type_id int[],e_date date[]) 
returns table (
  entity_first_name  TEXT,
  patient_first_name TEXT,
  business_entity_id INTEGER,
  payments_type_id  INTEGER,
  entry_date     DATE) as $$
begin
return query
SELECT
  entity_name,
  patient_name,
  business_entity_id,
  payment_type_id,
  entered_date
FROM v_payments
WHERE business_entity_id = ANY($1) 
and payment_type_id = ANY($2) 
and entered_date = any($3); 
end; 
$$ 
language plpgsql;
```

Now you can call it like below:

```sql
select * from get_patient_data('{1,2}','{5,4}','{''2020-01-01'',''2020-02-01''}')
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9760e9611e64a4e07377ac821d77c7a2)

As you have taken all the parameter of function as array then you have to provide it in array like above. you can change you conditions as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot Akhilesh Mishra for your prompt response and my issue was resolved . A bundle of thanks and best wishes from my side ......Really appreciated

Comment: You welcome. Please upvote if it is as per your expectation

Comment: i did it bro once a again thanks for your prompt response ....